# Is IIS balancing reliable for WCF servers?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, load-balancing

I have to create WCF servers farm (several workstations in Intranet environment that host WCF servers) and wonder how to implement load balancing.

Requirements are:

- If workstation is down requests should be automatically redirected to another one
- The workstation with minimum request processing time  should be chosen to handle incoming request

Questions are:

- Do IIS servers with NLB (that will host my WCF servers) meet my requirement?
- Can I use more compressed protocol than http to minimize traffic and still live with IIS?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLB will be fine, however, if you use a session based binding (wsHttpBinding or netTcpBinding_ then you have to enable sticky sessions

If you want full free load balancing then HTTP is the way to go and make sure you don;t have sessions. For lowest overhead use HTTP with the binary encoder (this requires a custom binding although it has been packaged by a number of people  - search for NetHttpBinding)